# kubectl exec "groups: cannot find name for group ID 40001"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I ran the `kubectl exec -it my_pod_name '/bin/bash' -n my_release_name` and it is returning message `groups: cannot find name for group ID 40001`. Not a blocker for what I need because I can still get to the command line of the container.

Comment: Can you share your pod/deployment template. This error generally occurs when you have specified some group using `runAsGroup` field.

Comment: Also your Dockerfile

Comment: @alltej Did you already fixed your problem? if not, post the requested info so we can help!

Comment: I have something like this in Dockerfile: 
`RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -d ${USER_HOME_DIR} ${USER}`
...
`RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${USER_HOME_DIR}`

Comment: please add it as edit on the question, and the deployment of the pod would ease the troubleshooting. Did you tried with any other bash pod like `kubectl run -i --tty --rm --image ubuntu test-shell -- /bin/bash`? does it return the error too?

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate by defining an extra PersistentVolume with "40001" gid in my YAML.

```
"annotations:
    pv.beta.kubernetes.io/gid: "40001"
```

If I apply the YAML (PV is created but never claimed) I see this message displayed on first container/pod only when I exec there.

```
 % kubectl exec -it mongo-0 -- bash                   
groups: cannot find name for group ID 40001
root@mongo-0:/# exit    
exit

 % kubectl exec -it mongo-1 -- bash
root@mongo-1:/# exit
exit
```

Presumably, the message disappears when PV is claimed, because the gid gets created. This is probably a bug in kube or kubectl.